# NSURL & PHP Connection

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, nsurl

i m trying to use this code for objective c connection with php mysql......

```
    NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://61.17.213.62/r_o_t/hemen/contactFile/chkbook.php?fname=%@&lname=%@&num=%@&eml=%@",firstname.text,lastname.text,mobile.text,email.text];
    NSLog(@"urlstr :%@",urlstr);

    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr] ];
    NSLog(@"the request :%@",theRequest);

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"returndata :%@",returnData);

    NSString *listData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"listData :%@",listData);
```

is there any other way to connect with php mysql....?

Comment: So...  what's your question? Is this not working? (it should work just fine) What errors are you getting? What have you debugged and figured out? Until you can provide more information, this isn't really a question.

Answer (score 0):

There is other way like using `ASIHTTPRequest` (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) but it will be almost the same.

1. Create the url
2. Create the request
3. Send the request
4. Get data